# Remove two characters from a string

Tags: swift

Below is my "services" variable. I want to remove first 2 characters from it. That is I want to replace ", " with ""

```
let services = ", EXTERNAL SERVICE, INTERNAL SERVICE"
```

I want to produce following result

```
let services = "EXTERNAL SERVICE, INTERNAL SERVICE"
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a solution based on the assumption that the string is composed with string concatenation from an array or loop separated by `", "`.

It converts the string to array, removes the empty item(s) and converts the string back to string

```
let services = ", EXTERNAL SERVICE, INTERNAL SERVICE"
               .components(separatedBy: ", ")
               .filter{ !$0.isEmpty }
               .joined(separator: ", ")
```

I guess the best solution is **not** to compose `services` by string concatenation before.

Comment: Hi Vadian, your solution is also working. Thanks for not only giving the solution, but for guiding about how not to compose variable by string concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

If you always want to remove the first two characters, use `String.substring(from:)`.

```
let services = ", EXTERNAL SERVICE, INTERNAL SERVICE"
let correctServices = services.substring(from: services.index(services.startIndex, offsetBy: 2))
```

> Output: "EXTERNAL SERVICE, INTERNAL SERVICE"

Comment: Thanks David, thats what I was looking for. And your answer saved me, it's working now. Thanks once again.

Comment: Glad I could help. If you found my answer useful, please consider accepting it.

Comment: Hi David, I upvoted it, but don't know why its not reflecting.

Comment: You don't yet have up vote privileges. You have to choose the checkmark icon to accept an answer. See [How does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to get rid of extraneous characters from the beginning, and maybe from the end. In your case you have two characters, but there is a more general way - which is trimming. This is from a playground

```
// Your original string
let string = ", EXTERNAL SERVICE, INTERNAL SERVICE"

// Create a character set for things to exclude - in this case whitespace, newlines and punctuation
let charset = CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines.union(.punctuationCharacters)

// Trimming removes the characters from the characterset from the beginning and the end of the string
let trimmedString = string.trimmingCharacters(in: charset) // -> "EXTERNAL SERVICE, INTERNAL SERVICE"
```

Comment: Hi Abizern, your solution is also working. Thanks a lot.